# Is it still necessary to check if a visitor's browser supports Ajax?

Tags: ajax, browser, activex

If I have Ajax code on my website:

1) Is it still necessary to check if a user's browser supports Ajax? Don't they all?

2) if so, is there an non-ActiveX approach to check this? I'd really like to avoid ActiveX as some security filters could flag it as potential malware.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a question of if browsers support 'ajax', this is just a pithy term used to describe the process of a client retreiving data from a server via Javascript, typically asynchronously, and typically using the [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) object.

This object is [not defined by IE 5-6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Support_in_Internet_Explorer_versions_5.2C_5.5_and_6), so you have to write code to compensate, or use a library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) which encapsulates this.

So, what you should be asking is whether your site gracefully degrades if Javascript is not available on the client. i.e. can users still get to the content without Javascript?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification that the issues isn't if the browser supports AJAX but the question if the clients has JavaScript turn on and what library you're using.